# Devise rails 3.1.3 No route matches [DELETE] "/users/sign_out"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am having an issue using devise 1.1.9 and rails 3.1.3 with the sign out link.

```
<%= link_to 'sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
```

after researching this for quite a while the only answers I could were all for people missing the :method => :delete in the sign out link, as you can see I have that method in my link. I also tried

```
<%= link_to('sign out', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>
```

rake routes

```
  new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
      user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
  destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)                         {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
      user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                         {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
 new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                     {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                    {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                   PUT    /users/password(.:format)                         {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
 user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
 new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                          {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                             {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                   PUT    /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                   DELETE /users(.:format)                                  {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
                   POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
   new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"comments"}
  edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"comments"}
   article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
                   PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"comments"}
                   DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"comments"}
          articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
                   POST   /articles(.:format)                               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
       new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}
      edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
           article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
                   PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
                   DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
              root        /                                                 {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
```

any help is greatly appreciated

**Update:**

An answer below suggested changing
    config.sign_out_via = :get
to :delete but I don't have that line in the following devise.rb file

```
# Use this hook to configure devise mailer, warden hooks and so forth. The first
# four configuration values can also be set straight in your models.
Devise.setup do |config|
# ==> Mailer Configuration
# Configure the e-mail address which will be shown in DeviseMailer.
config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me@config-initializers-devise.com"

# Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
# config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"

# ==> ORM configuration
# Load and configure the ORM. Supports :active_record (default) and
# :mongoid (bson_ext recommended) by default. Other ORMs may be
# available as additional gems.
require 'devise/orm/active_record'

# ==> Configuration for any authentication mechanism
# Configure which keys are used when authenticating an user. By default is
# just :email. You can configure it to use [:username, :subdomain], so for
# authenticating an user, both parameters are required. Remember that those
# parameters are used only when authenticating and not when retrieving from
# session. If you need permissions, you should implement that in a before filter.
 config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

# Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
 config.params_authenticatable = true

# Tell if authentication through HTTP Basic Auth is enabled. False by default.
# config.http_authenticatable = false

# Set this to true to use Basic Auth for AJAX requests.  True by default.
# config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

# The realm used in Http Basic Authentication
# config.http_authentication_realm = "Application"

# ==> Configuration for :database_authenticatable
# For bcrypt, this is the cost for hashing the password and defaults to 10. If
# using other encryptors, it sets how many times you want the password re-encrypted.
config.stretches = 10

# Define which will be the encryption algorithm. Devise also supports encryptors
# from others authentication tools as :clearance_sha1, :authlogic_sha512 (then
# you should set stretches above to 20 for default behavior) and :restful_authentication_sha1
# (then you should set stretches to 10, and copy REST_AUTH_SITE_KEY to pepper)
config.encryptor = :bcrypt

# Setup a pepper to generate the encrypted password.
config.pepper =   "hidden"

# ==> Configuration for :confirmable
# The time you want to give your user to confirm his account. During this time
# he will be able to access your application without confirming. Default is nil.
# When confirm_within is zero, the user won't be able to sign in without confirming. 
# You can use this to let your user access some features of your application 
# without confirming the account, but blocking it after a certain period 
# (ie 2 days). 
# config.confirm_within = 2.days

# ==> Configuration for :rememberable
# The time the user will be remembered without asking for credentials again.
# config.remember_for = 2.weeks

# If true, a valid remember token can be re-used between multiple browsers.
# config.remember_across_browsers = true

# If true, extends the user's remember period when remembered via cookie.
# config.extend_remember_period = false

# ==> Configuration for :validatable
# Range for password length
 config.password_length = 6..20

# Regex to use to validate the email address
 config.email_regexp = /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i

# ==> Configuration for :timeoutable
# The time you want to timeout the user session without activity. After this
# time the user will be asked for credentials again.
# config.timeout_in = 10.minutes

# ==> Configuration for :lockable
# Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
# :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
# :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
# config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

# Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
# :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
# :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
# :both  = Enables both strategies
# :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
# config.unlock_strategy = :both

# Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
# is failed attempts.
# config.maximum_attempts = 20

# Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
# config.unlock_in = 1.hour

# ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
# Defines name of the authentication token params key
# config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

# ==> Scopes configuration
# Turn scoped views on. Before rendering "sessions/new", it will first check for
# "users/sessions/new". It's turned off by default because it's slower if you
# are using only default views.
 config.scoped_views = true

# Configure the default scope given to Warden. By default it's the first
# devise role declared in your routes.
# config.default_scope = :user

# Configure sign_out behavior. 
# By default sign_out is scoped (i.e. /users/sign_out affects only :user scope).
# In case of sign_out_all_scopes set to true any logout action will sign out all active scopes.
 config.sign_out_all_scopes = true

# ==> Navigation configuration
# Lists the formats that should be treated as navigational. Formats like
# :html, should redirect to the sign in page when the user does not have
# access, but formats like :xml or :json, should return 401.
# If you have any extra navigational formats, like :iphone or :mobile, you
# should add them to the navigational formats lists. Default is [:html]
# config.navigational_formats = [:html, :iphone]


# ==> Warden configuration
# If you want to use other strategies, that are not (yet) supported by Devise,
# you can configure them inside the config.warden block. The example below
# allows you to setup OAuth, using http://github.com/roman/warden_oauth
#
# config.warden do |manager|
#   manager.oauth(:twitter) do |twitter|
#     twitter.consumer_secret = <YOUR CONSUMER SECRET>
#     twitter.consumer_key  = <YOUR CONSUMER KEY>
#     twitter.options :site => 'http://twitter.com'
#   end
#   manager.default_strategies(:scope => :user).unshift :twitter_oauth
# end
end
```

and adding the line

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

makes the server not start
thanks again

Comment: What is the issue that you're having? Are you getting errors? Is it just remaining signed in?

Answer (score 3):

The `users/sign_out` route in your routes output there is a GET request, not a DELETE.

I suspect you have something like this in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`:

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

By default, this option is set to `:delete`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change your config.sign_out_via = :get to :delete in your devise.rb file for several reasons.

1) This will change the delete action to a Get instead of Delete for 2

2) Every test you write here in there of, will be reflected as delete having an Get request. This means that the outcome of the action is incorrect.

3) The code you have is correct, and that is exactly what I have.

> 

As a beginner myself, let me take a stab of what I think the issue is.When I encountered this error I had confirm: "are you sure?" at the end of the erb. I changed the position around inside the erb tag and it worked. I think it may have to do with the routes not registering method: :delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
> rails generate devise:views
```

- My devise's views folder with this generator: http://j.mp/1cr6j6s
- Routing on routes.rb with `devise_for :users`

Comment: please provide little explanation too.

Comment: I mean if you has used this generator to generate all views, including /users/sign_out and routes. This is my devise's views folder http://j.mp/1cr6j6s and routing just with "devise_for :users" in routes.rb

Comment: A little explanation that you provided like now is helpful for the new user and must be present. Cheers !!